# How to get the time to milliseconds resolution python

Tags: python, datetime

I want to get the time in milli seconds resolution not microsecondsso basically my code is

```
now = datetime.now()
now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

But that write it to micro I want just to keep the first 3 digits of the microseconds so some kinda like %3f but ofcourse that is not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple:

```
now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]
```

This just slices the string to get rid of the last three characters of it.

Answer (score 0):

Subsecond resolution without full seconds:

```
time.time() % 1
0.3413050174713135
```

Or if you insist on milliseconds *alone*, then:

```
round(time.time() * 1000) % 1000
228.0
```

Add an `int(...)` if you don't like empty fractional part :)